# esp-gdbstub compilation errors

Tags: c, makefile, gdb, esp8266

I'm trying to use [esp-gdbstub](https://github.com/espressif/esp-gdbstub) to debug the code written to control mod-wifi-esp8266-dev. Here is my original makefile:

```
#You can build this example in three ways:
# 'separate' - Separate espfs and binaries, no OTA upgrade
# 'combined' - Combined firmware blob, no OTA upgrade
# 'ota' - Combined firmware blob with OTA upgrades.
#Please do a 'make clean' after changing this.
OUTPUT_TYPE=separate
#OUTPUT_TYPE=combined
#OUTPUT_TYPE=ota

#SPI flash size, in K
ESP_SPI_FLASH_SIZE_K=1024
#0: QIO, 1: QOUT, 2: DIO, 3: DOUT
ESP_FLASH_MODE=0
#0: 40MHz, 1: 26MHz, 2: 20MHz, 15: 80MHz
ESP_FLASH_FREQ_DIV=0


ifeq ("$(OUTPUT_TYPE)","separate")
#In case of separate ESPFS and binaries, set the pos and length of the ESPFS here. 
ESPFS_POS = 0x18000
ESPFS_SIZE = 0x28000
endif

# Output directors to store intermediate compiled files
# relative to the project directory
BUILD_BASE  = build
FW_BASE     = firmware

# Base directory for the compiler. Needs a / at the end; if not set it'll use the tools that are in
# the PATH.
XTENSA_TOOLS_ROOT ?= /Volumes/case-sensitive/esp-open-sdk/xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/

# base directory of the ESP8266 SDK package, absolute
#SDK_BASE   ?= /Volumes/case-sensitive/esp-open-sdk/sdk
SDK_BASE = /Users/halasz/Projects/Iskola/Mgr/Lienka/esp_iot_sdk_v1.4.0

# Opensdk patches stdint.h when compiled with an internal SDK. If you run into compile problems pertaining to
# redefinition of int types, try setting this to 'yes'.
USE_OPENSDK?=no

#Esptool.py path and port
ESPTOOL     ?= /Volumes/case-sensitive/esp-open-sdk/xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/esptool.py
ESPPORT     ?= /dev/cu.usbserial
#ESPPORT        ?= /dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART
#ESPDELAY indicates seconds to wait between flashing the two binary images
ESPDELAY    ?= 3
ESPBAUD     ?= 460800

#Appgen path and name
APPGEN      ?= $(SDK_BASE)/tools/gen_appbin.py

# name for the target project
TARGET      = httpd

# which modules (subdirectories) of the project to include in compiling
MODULES     = mdns driver user
EXTRA_INCDIR    = include libesphttpd/include library

# libraries used in this project, mainly provided by the SDK
LIBS        = c gcc hal phy pp net80211 wpa main lwip crypto
#Add in esphttpd lib
LIBS += esphttpd

# compiler flags using during compilation of source files
CFLAGS      = -Os -ggdb -std=gnu99 -Wpointer-arith -Wundef -Wall -Wl,-EL -fno-inline-functions \
        -nostdlib -mlongcalls -mtext-section-literals  -D__ets__ -DICACHE_FLASH \
        -Wno-address

# linker flags used to generate the main object file
LDFLAGS     = -nostdlib -Wl,--no-check-sections -u call_user_start -Wl,-static


# various paths from the SDK used in this project
SDK_LIBDIR  = lib
SDK_LDDIR   = ld
SDK_INCDIR  = include include/json

# select which tools to use as compiler, librarian and linker
CC      := $(XTENSA_TOOLS_ROOT)xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc
AR      := $(XTENSA_TOOLS_ROOT)xtensa-lx106-elf-ar
LD      := $(XTENSA_TOOLS_ROOT)xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc
OBJCOPY := $(XTENSA_TOOLS_ROOT)xtensa-lx106-elf-objcopy

#Additional (maybe generated) ld scripts to link in
EXTRA_LD_SCRIPTS:=


####
#### no user configurable options below here
####
SRC_DIR     := $(MODULES)
BUILD_DIR   := $(addprefix $(BUILD_BASE)/,$(MODULES))

SDK_LIBDIR  := $(addprefix $(SDK_BASE)/,$(SDK_LIBDIR))
SDK_INCDIR  := $(addprefix -I$(SDK_BASE)/,$(SDK_INCDIR))

SRC     := $(foreach sdir,$(SRC_DIR),$(wildcard $(sdir)/*.c))
ASMSRC      = $(foreach sdir,$(SRC_DIR),$(wildcard $(sdir)/*.S))
OBJ     = $(patsubst %.c,$(BUILD_BASE)/%.o,$(SRC))
OBJ     += $(patsubst %.S,$(BUILD_BASE)/%.o,$(ASMSRC))
APP_AR      := $(addprefix $(BUILD_BASE)/,$(TARGET)_app.a)


V ?= $(VERBOSE)
ifeq ("$(V)","1")
Q :=
vecho := @true
else
Q := @
vecho := @echo
endif

ifeq ("$(USE_OPENSDK)","yes")
CFLAGS      += -DUSE_OPENSDK
else
CFLAGS      += -D_STDINT_H
endif

ifeq ("$(GZIP_COMPRESSION)","yes")
CFLAGS      += -DGZIP_COMPRESSION
endif

ifeq ("$(USE_HEATSHRINK)","yes")
CFLAGS      += -DESPFS_HEATSHRINK
endif

ifeq ("$(ESPFS_POS)","")
#No hardcoded espfs position: link it in with the binaries.
LIBS += webpages-espfs
else
#Hardcoded espfs location: Pass espfs position to rest of code
CFLAGS += -DESPFS_POS=$(ESPFS_POS) -DESPFS_SIZE=$(ESPFS_SIZE)
endif

ifeq ("$(OUTPUT_TYPE)","ota")
CFLAGS += -DOTA_FLASH_SIZE_K=$(ESP_SPI_FLASH_SIZE_K)
endif


#Define default target. If not defined here the one in the included Makefile is used as the default one.
default-tgt: all

define maplookup
$(patsubst $(strip $(1)):%,%,$(filter $(strip $(1)):%,$(2)))
endef


#Include options and target specific to the OUTPUT_TYPE
include Makefile.$(OUTPUT_TYPE)

#Add all prefixes to paths
LIBS        := $(addprefix -l,$(LIBS))
ifeq ("$(LD_SCRIPT_USR1)", "")
LD_SCRIPT   := $(addprefix -T$(SDK_BASE)/$(SDK_LDDIR)/,$(LD_SCRIPT))
else
LD_SCRIPT_USR1  := $(addprefix -T$(SDK_BASE)/$(SDK_LDDIR)/,$(LD_SCRIPT_USR1))
LD_SCRIPT_USR2  := $(addprefix -T$(SDK_BASE)/$(SDK_LDDIR)/,$(LD_SCRIPT_USR2))
endif
INCDIR  := $(addprefix -I,$(SRC_DIR))
EXTRA_INCDIR    := $(addprefix -I,$(EXTRA_INCDIR))
MODULE_INCDIR   := $(addsuffix /include,$(INCDIR))

ESP_FLASH_SIZE_IX=$(call maplookup,$(ESP_SPI_FLASH_SIZE_K),512:0 1024:2 2048:5 4096:6)
ESPTOOL_FREQ=$(call maplookup,$(ESP_FLASH_FREQ_DIV),0:40m 1:26m 2:20m 0xf:80m 15:80m)
ESPTOOL_MODE=$(call maplookup,$(ESP_FLASH_MODE),0:qio 1:qout 2:dio 3:dout)
ESPTOOL_SIZE=$(call maplookup,$(ESP_SPI_FLASH_SIZE_K),512:4m 256:2m 1024:8m 2048:16m 4096:322m-c1)

ESPTOOL_OPTS=--port $(ESPPORT) --baud $(ESPBAUD)
ESPTOOL_FLASHDEF=--flash_freq $(ESPTOOL_FREQ) --flash_mode $(ESPTOOL_MODE) --flash_size $(ESPTOOL_SIZE)

vpath %.c $(SRC_DIR)
vpath %.S $(SRC_DIR)

define compile-objects
$1/%.o: %.c
    $(vecho) "CC $$<"
    $(Q) $(CC) $(INCDIR) $(MODULE_INCDIR) $(EXTRA_INCDIR) $(SDK_INCDIR) $(CFLAGS)  -c $$< -o $$@

$1/%.o: %.S
    $(vecho) "CC $$<"
    $(Q) $(CC) $(INCDIR) $(MODULE_INCDIR) $(EXTRA_INCDIR) $(SDK_INCDIR) $(CFLAGS)  -c $$< -o $$@
endef

.PHONY: all checkdirs clean libesphttpd default-tgt

all: checkdirs $(TARGET_OUT) $(FW_BASE)

libesphttpd/Makefile:
    $(Q) echo "No libesphttpd submodule found. Using git to fetch it..."
    $(Q) git submodule init
    $(Q) git submodule update

libesphttpd: libesphttpd/Makefile
    $(Q) make -C libesphttpd USE_OPENSDK=$(USE_OPENSDK)

$(APP_AR): libesphttpd $(OBJ)
    $(vecho) "AR $@"
    $(Q) $(AR) cru $@ $(OBJ)

checkdirs: $(BUILD_DIR)

$(BUILD_DIR):
    $(Q) mkdir -p $@

clean:
    $(Q) make -C libesphttpd clean
    $(Q) rm -f $(APP_AR)
    $(Q) rm -f $(TARGET_OUT)
    $(Q) find $(BUILD_BASE) -type f | xargs rm -f
    $(Q) rm -rf $(FW_BASE)


$(foreach bdir,$(BUILD_DIR),$(eval $(call compile-objects,$(bdir))))
```

I have tried to follow the instructions from the usage section:

- Grab the gdbstub project and put the files in a directory called 'gdbstub' in your project. You can do this either by checking out the Git repo, or adding the Git repo as a submodule to your project if it's already in Git. **(DONE)**
- Modify your Makefile. You'll need to include the gdbstub sources: if your Makefile is structured like the ones in the Espressif examples, you can add `gdbstub` to the `SUBDIRS` define and `gdbstub/libgdbstub.a` to the `COMPONENTS_eagle.app.v6` define. Also, you probably want to add `-ggdb` to your compiler flags (`TARGET_LDFLAGS`) and, if you are debugging, change any optimation flags (-Os, -O2 etc) into `-Og`. Finally, make sure your Makefile also compiles .S files.

And here comes the problem. I do not have SUBDIRS define, but I have found row

```
MODULES     = mdns driver user
```

so maybe here at the end should I add gdbstub like this?

```
MODULES     = mdns driver user gdbstub
```

I have not found anything like `COMPONENTS_eagle.app.v6`, so I do not know, where to put `gdbstub/libgdbstub.a`. `-ggdb` I have had in `CFLAGS` (not `TARGET_LDFLAGS`), and also had `-Os` in `CFLAGS` so changed it to `-Og`.

- Configure gdbstub by editting gdbstub-cfg.h. There are a bunch of options you can tweak: FreeRTOS or bare SDK, private exception/breakpoint stack, console redirection to GDB, wait till debugger attachment etc. You can also configure the options by including the proper -Dwhatever gcc flags in your Makefiles. **(DID NOT CHANGED ANYTHING IN THIS FILE)**

gdbstub-cfg.h:

```
#ifndef GDBSTUB_CFG_H
#define  GDBSTUB_CFG_H

/*
Enable this define if you're using the RTOS SDK. It will use a custom exception handler instead of the HAL
and do some other magic to make everything work and compile under FreeRTOS.
*/
#ifndef GDBSTUB_FREERTOS
#define GDBSTUB_FREERTOS 1
#endif

/*
Enable this to make the exception and debugging handlers switch to a private stack. This will use 
up 1K of RAM, but may be useful if you're debugging stack or stack pointer corruption problems. It's
normally disabled because not many situations need it. If for some reason the GDB communication 
stops when you run into an error in your code, try enabling this.
*/
#ifndef GDBSTUB_USE_OWN_STACK
#define GDBSTUB_USE_OWN_STACK 0
#endif

/*
If this is defined, gdbstub will break the program when you press Ctrl-C in gdb. it does this by
hooking the UART interrupt. Unfortunately, this means receiving stuff over the serial port won't
work for your program anymore. This will fail if your program sets an UART interrupt handler after
the gdbstub_init call.
*/
#ifndef GDBSTUB_CTRLC_BREAK
#define GDBSTUB_CTRLC_BREAK 1
#endif

/*
Enabling this will redirect console output to GDB. This basically means that printf/os_printf output 
will show up in your gdb session, which is useful if you use gdb to do stuff. It also means that if
you use a normal terminal, you can't read the printfs anymore.
*/
#ifndef GDBSTUB_REDIRECT_CONSOLE_OUTPUT
#define GDBSTUB_REDIRECT_CONSOLE_OUTPUT 1
#endif

/*
Enable this if you want the GDB stub to wait for you to attach GDB before running. It does this by
breaking in the init routine; use the gdb 'c' command (continue) to start the program.
*/
#ifndef GDBSTUB_BREAK_ON_INIT
#define GDBSTUB_BREAK_ON_INIT 1
#endif

/*
Function attributes for function types.
Gdbstub functions are placed in flash or IRAM using attributes, as defined here. The gdbinit function
(and related) can always be in flash, because it's called in the normal code flow. The rest of the
gdbstub functions can be in flash too, but only if there's no chance of them being called when the
flash somehow is disabled (eg during SPI operations or flash write/erase operations). If the routines
are called when the flash is disabled (eg due to a Ctrl-C at the wrong time), the ESP8266 will most 
likely crash.
*/
#define ATTR_GDBINIT    ICACHE_FLASH_ATTR
#ifndef ATTR_GDBFN
#define ATTR_GDBFN      
#endif

#endif
```

- In your user_main.c, add an `#include <../gdbstub/gdbstub.h>` and call `gdbstub_init();` somewhere in user_main. **(DONE)**
- Compile and flash your board. **(PROBLEM WITH COMPILATION)**

When compiling the program, it shows me a lot of errors:

```
AR libesphttpd.a
wifi/wifi.tpl (55%, heatshrink)
wifi/.DS_Store (15%, heatshrink)
wifi/140medley.min.js (74%, heatshrink)
wifi/connecting.html (61%, heatshrink)
wifi/icons.png (100%, none)
wifi/style.css (73%, heatshrink)
index.tpl (68%, heatshrink)
websocket/index.html (52%, heatshrink)
cats/.DS_Store (15%, heatshrink)
.DS_Store (16%, heatshrink)
test/index.html (72%, heatshrink)
test/test.js (38%, heatshrink)
lienkaweb/index.html (38%, heatshrink)
lienkaweb/images/up.png (100%, none)
lienkaweb/images/down.png (100%, none)
lienkaweb/images/up_hover.png (100%, none)
lienkaweb/images/left.png (100%, none)
lienkaweb/images/left_hover.png (100%, none)
lienkaweb/images/down_hover.png (100%, none)
lienkaweb/images/right_hover.png (100%, none)
lienkaweb/images/right.png (100%, none)
lienkaweb/script.js (21%, heatshrink)
lienkaweb/style.css (44%, heatshrink)
flash/index.html (54%, heatshrink)
flash/140medley.min.js (74%, heatshrink)
flash/style.css (59%, heatshrink)
style.css (78%, heatshrink)
led.tpl (72%, heatshrink)
AR build/httpd_app.a
GEN ldscript_memspecific.ld
LD build/httpd.out
/Volumes/case-sensitive/esp-open-sdk/xtensa-lx106-elf/lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.5/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/ld:ldscript_memspecific.ld:1: warning: redeclaration of memory region `irom0_0_seg'
/Volumes/case-sensitive/esp-open-sdk/xtensa-lx106-elf/lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.5/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/ld: build/httpd.out section `.text' will not fit in region `iram1_0_seg'
build/httpd_app.a(gdbstub.o):(.irom0.text+0x4): undefined reference to `user_fatal_exception_handler'
build/httpd_app.a(gdbstub.o): In function `install_exceptions':
gdbstub.c:(.irom0.text+0x28): undefined reference to `_xt_isr_attach'
gdbstub.c:(.irom0.text+0x2c): undefined reference to `_xt_isr_unmask'
build/httpd_app.a(gdbstub.o): In function `install_uart_hdlr':
/Users/halasz/Projects/Iskola/Mgr/Lienka-esphttpd/esphttpd/gdbstub/gdbstub.c:762: undefined reference to `_xt_isr_attach'
/Users/halasz/Projects/Iskola/Mgr/Lienka-esphttpd/esphttpd/gdbstub/gdbstub.c:764: undefined reference to `_xt_isr_unmask'
/Users/halasz/Projects/Iskola/Mgr/Lienka-esphttpd/esphttpd/gdbstub/gdbstub.c:765: undefined reference to `os_install_putc1'
build/httpd_app.a(gdbstub.o): In function `gdbstub_init':
/Users/halasz/Projects/Iskola/Mgr/Lienka-esphttpd/esphttpd/gdbstub/gdbstub.c:776: undefined reference to `os_install_putc1'
/Volumes/case-sensitive/esp-open-sdk/xtensa-lx106-elf/lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.5/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/lib/libc.a(lib_a-wsetup.o):(.literal+0x0): undefined reference to `_free_r'
/Volumes/case-sensitive/esp-open-sdk/xtensa-lx106-elf/lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.5/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/lib/libc.a(lib_a-wsetup.o): In function `__swsetup_r':
/Volumes/case-sensitive/esp-open-sdk/crosstool-NG/.build/src/newlib-2.0.0/newlib/libc/stdio/wsetup.c:57: undefined reference to `_free_r'
/Volumes/case-sensitive/esp-open-sdk/xtensa-lx106-elf/lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.5/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/lib/libc.a(lib_a-fflush.o): In function `__sflush_r':
/Volumes/case-sensitive/esp-open-sdk/crosstool-NG/.build/src/newlib-2.0.0/newlib/libc/stdio/fflush.c:162: undefined reference to `_free_r'
/Volumes/case-sensitive/esp-open-sdk/xtensa-lx106-elf/lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.5/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/lib/libc.a(lib_a-findfp.o):(.literal+0x4): undefined reference to `_malloc_r'
/Volumes/case-sensitive/esp-open-sdk/xtensa-lx106-elf/lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.5/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/lib/libc.a(lib_a-findfp.o): In function `__sfmoreglue':
/Volumes/case-sensitive/esp-open-sdk/crosstool-NG/.build/src/newlib-2.0.0/newlib/libc/stdio/findfp.c:88: undefined reference to `_malloc_r'
/Volumes/case-sensitive/esp-open-sdk/xtensa-lx106-elf/lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.5/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/lib/libc.a(lib_a-makebuf.o):(.literal+0x8): undefined reference to `_fstat_r'
/Volumes/case-sensitive/esp-open-sdk/xtensa-lx106-elf/lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.5/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/lib/libc.a(lib_a-makebuf.o): In function `__smakebuf_r':
/Volumes/case-sensitive/esp-open-sdk/crosstool-NG/.build/src/newlib-2.0.0/newlib/libc/stdio/makebuf.c:59: undefined reference to `_fstat_r'
/Volumes/case-sensitive/esp-open-sdk/crosstool-NG/.build/src/newlib-2.0.0/newlib/libc/stdio/makebuf.c:95: undefined reference to `_malloc_r'
/Volumes/case-sensitive/esp-open-sdk/xtensa-lx106-elf/lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.5/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/lib/libc.a(lib_a-stdio.o):(.literal+0x0): undefined reference to `_read_r'
/Volumes/case-sensitive/esp-open-sdk/xtensa-lx106-elf/lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.5/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/lib/libc.a(lib_a-stdio.o):(.literal+0x4): undefined reference to `_lseek_r'
/Volumes/case-sensitive/esp-open-sdk/xtensa-lx106-elf/lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.5/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/lib/libc.a(lib_a-stdio.o):(.literal+0x8): undefined reference to `_write_r'
/Volumes/case-sensitive/esp-open-sdk/xtensa-lx106-elf/lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.5/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/lib/libc.a(lib_a-stdio.o):(.literal+0xc): undefined reference to `_close_r'
/Volumes/case-sensitive/esp-open-sdk/xtensa-lx106-elf/lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.5/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/lib/libc.a(lib_a-stdio.o): In function `__sread':
/Volumes/case-sensitive/esp-open-sdk/crosstool-NG/.build/src/newlib-2.0.0/newlib/libc/stdio/stdio.c:48: undefined reference to `_read_r'
/Volumes/case-sensitive/esp-open-sdk/xtensa-lx106-elf/lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.5/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/lib/libc.a(lib_a-stdio.o): In function `__swrite':
/Volumes/case-sensitive/esp-open-sdk/crosstool-NG/.build/src/newlib-2.0.0/newlib/libc/stdio/stdio.c:89: undefined reference to `_lseek_r'
/Volumes/case-sensitive/esp-open-sdk/crosstool-NG/.build/src/newlib-2.0.0/newlib/libc/stdio/stdio.c:97: undefined reference to `_write_r'
/Volumes/case-sensitive/esp-open-sdk/xtensa-lx106-elf/lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.5/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/lib/libc.a(lib_a-stdio.o): In function `__sseek':
/Volumes/case-sensitive/esp-open-sdk/crosstool-NG/.build/src/newlib-2.0.0/newlib/libc/stdio/stdio.c:117: undefined reference to `_lseek_r'
/Volumes/case-sensitive/esp-open-sdk/xtensa-lx106-elf/lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.5/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/lib/libc.a(lib_a-stdio.o): In function `__sclose':
/Volumes/case-sensitive/esp-open-sdk/crosstool-NG/.build/src/newlib-2.0.0/newlib/libc/stdio/stdio.c:135: undefined reference to `_close_r'
/Volumes/case-sensitive/esp-open-sdk/xtensa-lx106-elf/lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.5/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/lib/libc.a(isatty.o): In function `_isatty_r':
/Volumes/case-sensitive/esp-open-sdk/crosstool-NG/.build/src/newlib-2.0.0/newlib/libc/sys/xtensa/isatty.c:13: undefined reference to `_fstat_r'
/Volumes/case-sensitive/esp-open-sdk/xtensa-lx106-elf/lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.5/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/lib/libc.a(lib_a-fclose.o): In function `_fclose_r':
/Volumes/case-sensitive/esp-open-sdk/crosstool-NG/.build/src/newlib-2.0.0/newlib/libc/stdio/fclose.c:102: undefined reference to `_free_r'
/Volumes/case-sensitive/esp-open-sdk/crosstool-NG/.build/src/newlib-2.0.0/newlib/libc/stdio/fclose.c:104: undefined reference to `_free_r'
/Volumes/case-sensitive/esp-open-sdk/crosstool-NG/.build/src/newlib-2.0.0/newlib/libc/stdio/fclose.c:106: undefined reference to `_free_r'
/Volumes/case-sensitive/esp-open-sdk/xtensa-lx106-elf/lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.5/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/lib/libc.a(lib_a-fvwrite.o):(.literal+0x0): undefined reference to `_realloc_r'
/Volumes/case-sensitive/esp-open-sdk/xtensa-lx106-elf/lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.5/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/lib/libc.a(lib_a-fvwrite.o): In function `__sfvwrite_r':
/Volumes/case-sensitive/esp-open-sdk/crosstool-NG/.build/src/newlib-2.0.0/newlib/libc/stdio/fvwrite.c:143: undefined reference to `_malloc_r'
/Volumes/case-sensitive/esp-open-sdk/crosstool-NG/.build/src/newlib-2.0.0/newlib/libc/stdio/fvwrite.c:154: undefined reference to `_realloc_r'
/Volumes/case-sensitive/esp-open-sdk/crosstool-NG/.build/src/newlib-2.0.0/newlib/libc/stdio/fvwrite.c:160: undefined reference to `_free_r'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [build/httpd.out] Error 1
```

Could you help me please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the SUBDIR and COMPONENTS_eagle.app.v6 as following (in your Makefile).

COMPONENTS_eagle.app.v6

SUBDIRS=                \
    gdbstub

COMPONENTS_eagle.app.v6 =           \
        gdbstub/libgdbstub.a

Reference:
https://github.com/espressif/esp-gdbstub